# Как не потерять информацию при преобразовании из char в byte

Tags: java, массивы, char

Есть массив `byte B[64]` и массив `Sbox[]` из 256 элементов - но большинство чисел больше 127. Нужно выполнить подстановку типа:

```
byte [] B = new byte[64];  //message of 512 bits
//here 256 elements, but some of them more than 127
Sbox [] = {0xFC, 0xEE....}; 

for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    B [i] = (byte) (Sbox(B[i]))
```

Как мне хранить `Sbox[]` или какое делать преобразование чтоб не потерять информацию?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Судя по заголовку вопроса, массив Sbox имеет тип char[]. char в java занимает 2 байта. Вы хотите 256*2=512 байт запихнуть в 64? Да даже, судя по отрезку кода, если вы берете только первые 64 элемента массива Sbox, 128 байт в 64 преобразовать в общем случае не удастся.